# Google Cloud SQL Restore BAK file

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql, google-iam

I am new in Google Cloud. I created a Cloud SQL Instance and I need to restore the data from a `.bak` file. I have the `.bak` file in a GCS bucket, and I am trying to restore using Microsoft Management Studio -> Task -> Restore. But I'm not able to access the file.

Can anyone help me with the procedure on how to restore from a `.bak` file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the Cloud SQL service Account access to the bucket where the file is saved.

On [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/using-cloud-shell) run the following:

```
gcloud sql instances describe [INSTANCE_NAME]
```

On the output search for the field "serviceAccountEmailAddress" an copy the SA email.

Then again on cloud shell run the following:

```
gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:<<SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL>:legacyBucketWriter gs://<<BUCKET_NAME>>


gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:<<SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL>:objectViewer gs://<<BUCKET_NAME>>
```

That should give the service account permission to access the bucket and retrieve the file, also here is [the guide](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/import-export/importing#importing_the_bak_file) on doing the import, take in mind that doing the import will override all the data on the DB.

Also remember that:

> You cannot import a database that was exported from a higher version of SQL Server. For example, if you exported a SQL Server 2017 Enterprise version, you cannot import it into a SQL Server 2017 Standard version.

Answer (score 0):

To restore DB from .bak file run this command :

```
gcloud sql import bak SQL_SERVER_INSTANCE_NAME gs://BUCKET_NAME/file.bak --database=DATABASE_NAME
```

Don't forget to give the Cloud SQL service Account access to the bucket where the file is stored.

[from google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/import/bak)