# Importing data from a BAK file in Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-iam

I'm trying to import a `.bak` but getting this message `An unknown error occurred` no other details?

The error message only contains `An unknown error occurred` with no other details so getting difficult to debug.

I'm following this documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/import-export/importing#importing_data_from_a_bak_file_in

This question is related to this but I'm importing from Google console.
[Google Cloud SQL Restore BAK file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61915558/google-cloud-sql-restore-bak-file)

Error message image

[image: img_error_msg]

Comment: Have you verified if the default service account used by the instance has read permissions on the bucket you're using? you get the service account by going into the Cloud Console -> SQL -> Click on the instance name and search for "Service account". Then verify if you have read permissions on the bucket for that service account.

Comment: @Emmanuel Yes, it has read permission because before this error I was getting these errors while trying to import `.bak` file which I've already resolved.
**1) Multiple databases detected in BAK file. Only importing a single database is supported.**
**2) 80 is not a supported compatibility level. Supported: [140, 130, 120, 110, 100]**

Comment: Is there more information on the logs inside the Cloud Console?

Comment: no only this information `An unknown error occurred`.

Comment: I think that your best bet is to [contact GCP support](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs#contacting_technical_support), because the information provided by the console isn't enough to help you and the real reason behind this error could be anything. You can also contact them directly by going inside the [console](https://console.cloud.google.com/support/)

Comment: Yes, I've open a ticket on https://issuetracker.google.com. Thanks Emmanuel. :)

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved. I think it was space issue.
I created new `Google Cloud SQL` instance with higher space and then import the `.bak` file it got imported successfully.
I'm confuse that was it space issue or was it instance issue.